# Записать значение в ячейку по двум условиям

Tags: python, dataframe

Всем привет, имею:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'], 'column2': [100, 200, 300], 'column3': ['', 200,''], 'column4': [100,'','']}) 
df
```

на выходе

```
  column1  column2 column3 column4
0   name1      100             100
1   name2      200     200        
2   name3      300
```

**Задача**

В новую колонку "Итог":

- если вторая колонка равна четвертой, то вывести значение -
  "Условие_1",
- если вторая колонка равна третьей, то вывести значение
  из первой колонки,
- если условия не соблюдены -- оставить пустоту.

Итог должен быть таким:

```
  column1  column2 column3 column4              Итог
0   name1      100             100              Условие_1   
1   name2      200     200                      name2
2   name3      300
```

мое решение:

```
df['Итог'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Условие_1' if x['column2'] == x['column4'] else (df['column1'] if x['column2'] == x['column3'] else ''), axis=1)
```

дает странный результат

```
  column1  column2 column3 column4                   Итог
0   name1      100             100                       
1   name2      200     200                      Условие_1
2   name3      300                  [name1, name2, name3]
```

Собственно вопрос: почему значение вписывается в строчку где совпадения нет, а так же берет все значения из всей колонки, а не только одно?

Я уже решил это через select numpy, но очень хочется получить ответ, как это сделать через `apply`.

И, по возможности, дайте развернутый ответ -  очень хочется понять как работает, а не просто скопировать готовый код. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else (df['column1'] if 
      ^^ - тут должен быть x
```

У вас в одном месте вместо `x` написано `df`, а в остальном всё правильно работает. Я исправил только это место:

```
df['Итог'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Условие_1' if x['column2'] == x['column4'] else (x['column1'] if x['column2'] == x['column3'] else ''), axis=1)
```

Вывод:

```
  column1   column2 column3 column4 Итог
0   name1   100             100     Условие_1
1   name2   200     200             name2
2   name3   300
```

А объяснять тут вроде особо нечего, просто в `lambda` применён два раза тернарный оператор `x if condition else y` (второй раз - внутри `else`). А `lambda` тут оперирует строками, в `x` у вас строка, к элементам столбцов внутри которой вы обращаетесь.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: @Dikson Если ответ помог, поставьте плюс и отметьте ответ как правильный. Ну, если у вас есть на это права. )

Comment: К сожалению пока нет прав, но постараюсь вернуться когда заработаю реп, только первые вопросы)

Comment: @Dikson, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814) - это право есть у __всех__ зарегистрированных пользователей